# NSURL: reading file from external device within an iphone app

Tags: ios

I need to read a file from a iphone app which is daily new generated on my iMac.

Trying the following code would only work on the simulator, but not on the connected iphone.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/users/mick/documents/Data/Data.txt"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Trying that would not work at all:

```
NSURL* urlserver = [NSURL URLWithString:@"192.x.x.x/users/mick/documents/Data/Data.txt"];

NSData* dataServer = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlserver];
// DataServer == NULL
```

Both devices are in the same WLAN and/or the iphone is connected to the MAC, if that could help solving the problem.

Thanks in advance for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

To use `dataWithContentsOfURL:` as you are trying to do from a device, you should make sure that a web server is running on your Mac, so that it can handle the HTTP request coming from the iPhone. Actually, you would also need some server-side code that will handle the URL and give you back the file data.

The reason why the following works:

```
 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/users/mick/documents/Data/Data.txt"]
```

is that the simulator and the Mac are sharing the same filesystem.